# How to get next seven days in android?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

In my app, I need next seven days from the current day.
I tried the following solution but it is skipping some days.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
    String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i(TAG, day);
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Sunday 18-Oct-2015
Monday 19-Oct-2015
Wednesday 21-Oct-2015
Saturday 24-Oct-2015
Wednesday 28-Oct-2015
Monday 02-Nov-2015
Sunday 08-Nov-2015
```

I also tried `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`, `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` instead of `Calendar.DATE` but getting the same output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
    String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i(TAG, day);
}
```

You have one instance of calendar and are adding 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 days to it without resetting it. The above solution moves object creation to be within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

found a easiest way with java 8+

plusDays

```
  final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  final LocalDate plusDays = date.plusDays(7); 
  //if you want to show past 7 days, change to data.minusDays(7);
  final String formattedDate = plusDays.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")); // show is this format 09/30/2020
  System.out.println(formattedDate);  //09/30/2020
```

MinusDays

```
  final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  final LocalDate minusDays = date.minusDays(7); 
  final String formattedDate = minusDays.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")); 
  System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

dateTimeFormat has a lot of features inside, refer to
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/java8-datetimeformatter-example/